# Bootstrap .col-md-* error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="companies">
        <h3>Parteners &#38; Sponsor</h3>
        <p>Here is a quick view at the companies that we trust and help us.</p>
        <div class="sponsor">
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of Parteners & Sponsors section -->


.sp {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sponsor {
    text-align: center;
    border: 7px solid green;
}

.companies {
    border: 7px solid yellow;
}
```

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

As you can see from the CSS styling I the *.companies* class has a 7px green border, the *.sponsor* - a 7px yellow border. *.sp* has just a red border so that you can see it.

The *.sp* should be wrapped in a green container like in the image2 (In image2 I don't use the .col-md-4 class from bootstrap), instead it is showing like in the image1 (where I use the .col-md-4). .col-md-* or other classes from bootstrap work perfectly in other parts of the document.

Comment: You missed the row class?

Comment: Thx. Previously I was wrapping the entire .companies class in a .row, now wrapped just the three .sp divs. Solved.

Comment: @Petah post it as an answer.

Comment: @Gofilord I was on a tablet, so I couldn't provide a complete answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="companies">
        <h3>Parteners &#38; Sponsor</h3>
        <p>Here is a quick view at the companies that we trust and help us.</p>

        <div class="sponsor">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of Parteners & Sponsors section -->
```

This is how it should be. Thanks to everyone for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by something known as div collapsing, which means that the height of the div is reduced to Zero, the reason for that is the float of the divs with the class `col-md-4`, they have a `float:left;` style, that's why the parent is collapsing.

The solution is to clear the float after those div, so your html would be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="companies">
        <h3>Parteners &#38; Sponsor</h3>
        <p>Here is a quick view at the companies that we trust and help us.</p>
        <div class="sponsor">
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            <br style="clear:both;" />
       </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of Parteners & Sponsors section -->
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: May be, but wrapping .sp divs in a row work as it should. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the "companies" div size so the "sponsor" div fits in. idem for "sponsor" div for the "sp" div to fit in. That should resolve the problem with the borders.

Comment: No. The .companies height is set to auto. Wrapped the .sp divs in a .row class - this solved the problem.

http://funkyimg.com/i/K4k8.png

Mulțumesc pentru răspuns oricum :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** no changes in css only two changes in HTML you can get exact output as you wish.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="companies">
        <h3>Parteners &#38; Sponsor</h3>
        <p>Here is a quick view at the companies that we trust and help us.</p>
        <div class="sponsor clearfix">
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
            <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

why not do it "politically correct"?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="companies row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="sponsor row">
                        <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
                        <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
                        <div class="sp col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/sponsors/bt.png"></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of Parteners & Sponsors section -->
```